# Applescript: Keynote 6.6.2 start presentation

Tags: applescript, keynote

I checked this website: 
https://iworkautomation.com/keynote/document-play.html
and

I tried this code to start a Keynote presentation:

```
tell application "Keynote"
activate
if playing is false then tell the front document to start
end tell
```

But it doesn't work.
The only solution I found was sending keystroke:

```
tell application "Keynote"
activate
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "p" using {command down, option down}
end tell
```

Why the "start action" doesn't work?
I'm on Yosemite

Comment: The first snippet works fine for me with Keynote 7.1.1. Have you tried other versions of Keynote?

Comment: No, because I'm on early 2007 Imac and I can't install OSX Sierra, so I can't install Keynote 7.1.1...

Comment: Is working even this code for you:
tell application "Keynote" to set the bounds of window 1 to {0, 0, 200, 400}

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646342/how-to-resize-a-keynote-slideshow

Comment: Yes, that works fine for me. Is it not working for you? That would look like there's some other issue with AppleScripting Keynote for you then

Comment: I tried now with Sierra and Keynote 7.1.1 and it works right :)
Thanks for your support :)